# Cut string when find a space

Tags: php, html, string, space

I try to cut my string, just take everything until u find " "

```
$ret = $html->find('td[class="date"]'); 

$pole = array();
foreach ($ret as $pole) {
    $datum[] = $pole->innertext;    // getting text what i need from HTML(simple html dom)
    }   

   echo "$datum[0]";    //output of this is: 04.07.2013 Film Europe 


$text_arr = str_split($datum[0]);      //string to array
foreach($text_arr as $x){

if($x==" ") break;   //if find space stop!
echo $x;
}
```

I was 100% my code is right, but its not working , echo $x do nothing :), like if there was nothing stored in that variabile

Comment: `I was 100% my code is right, but its not working` mmm yes, I've heard this before.

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kIE3bU not that i would do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simpler version

```
$datum[0]="04.07.2013 Film Europe"; 
$x=explode(' ',trim($datum[0]));
echo $x[0]; //04.07.2013
```

Comment: It looks i had space on start as well, thats why it didnt work, anyway thanks guys :)

Comment: a +1 for the simple ways

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off by using explode this way:

```
$text_arr = explode(" ", $datum[0]);
echo $text_arr[0];
```

Forget about the foreach loop, just use the first element as it's already cut on the first space.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually you should check if the string contains what you want it to.
(for example there could be a senseless space at the beginning...)

check http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php